# Issues changing form's type to a custom base form type

Tags: delphi, inheritance, vcl

I have a number of existing forms which I need to convert to inherit from another base form `TfrmBase` instead of the normal `TForm`. This base form is a `TForm` with a little added functionality. All I do to convert them is...

1. add the base form's unit to the uses clause
2. change `class(TForm)` to `class(TfrmBase)`.

When I run the application, the `FormCreate` even is executed successfully, but when it comes to showing this form (application's main form), I get an exception:

`Class TPanel not found`

I do in fact have a panel on this form which was converted. The uses clause does in fact have `Vcl.ExtCtrls` added to it, where the `TPanel` comes from.

What do I need to do to fix this? Am I doing the right steps to convert these forms?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541404/how-can-i-add-a-border-to-every-form-in-my-application-without-modifying-each-fo

Comment: I would rather use repository and inheritance of that base form. It's easy. You just prepare that base form in designer (you can add some common components for instance), add the code for the new functionality and save it somewhere. Then you go to that form designer, right click and select `Add to Repository`. There you select some category, enter some title and save it. And then if you'll make a new form, you won't use `File / New / Form` menu as usually, but you'll use `File / New / Other`, there you find your saved form and in the bottom radio group select `Inherit`. That's all!

Comment: @TLama Indeed, but take a look at the related question I linked...

Comment: Well, so let's start to use it since now if you aren't doing so. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @TLama I will, thanks for the recommendation. I'm also working on restructuring the same software from scratch.

Comment: If the base form has anything in its .dfm you'll need to modify the derived .dfm too. Change object to inherited in the first line of the derived form .dfm.

Comment: I have seen some weird IDE bugs when you change a form so it inherits from a class that does not end in `Form`, if it's a form, or `DataModule` if it's a data module.  Including some runtime errors like class not found as you have seen.  So `TCustomReportForm` seems find, but `TfrmReport` as a base class, is not.  Not always able to reproduce.  (Maybe I'm paranoid?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out my problem while I was typing this question, which probably no one else would have thought to point out...

All I had to do is remove this base form from the automatically created forms, and it worked. Something I should have done in the first place.